# Get datediff from three tables

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff

How can I get the date difference based on schedule of the employee and First Time In and Last Time Out?

Below are the queries I'm using.

```
select * from tbl_payroll_schedule where id in (3, 17, 18)
```

Output:

```
id  schedule_description    time_in time_out    schedule_status
3   REST DAY            1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1
17  08:00 AM - 05:00 PM 1900-01-01 08:00:00.000 1900-01-01 17:00:00.000 1
18  08:00 AM - 12:00 PM 1900-01-01 08:00:00.000 1900-01-01 12:00:00.000 1

select mon.schedule_description as Monday,
        tue.schedule_description as Tuesday,
        wed.schedule_description as Wednesday,
        thu.schedule_description as Thursday,
        fri.schedule_description as Friday,
        sat.schedule_description as Saturday,
        sun.schedule_description as Sunday
        from employee_default_schedule ds

LEFT JOIN tbl_payroll_schedule mon on mon.id = ds.mon_sched
LEFT JOIN tbl_payroll_schedule tue on tue.id = ds.tues_sched
LEFT JOIN tbl_payroll_schedule wed on wed.id = ds.wed_sched
LEFT JOIN tbl_payroll_schedule thu on thu.id = ds.thurs_sched
LEFT JOIN tbl_payroll_schedule fri on fri.id = ds.fri_sched
LEFT JOIN tbl_payroll_schedule sat on sat.id = ds.sat_sched
LEFT JOIN tbl_payroll_schedule sun on sun.id = ds.sun_sched

WHERE ds.employee_id = 125
```

Output:
[image]

```
select ot.id,
        ot.employee_id as EID,
        (el.Last_Name + ', ' + el.First_Name) as Name, 
        FORMAT(ot.record_time, 'ddd MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss') as Time,
        (CASE WHEN ot.type = 0 then 'Time In'
             WHEN ot.type = 1 then 'Time Out'
        END) as Status
        from officer_timelogs ot
        left join tbl_Employee_MasterList el on el.ID = ot.employee_id
        where ot.employee_id = (CASE WHEN 125 = 0 THEN ot.employee_id else 125 END)
            and ot.record_time >= CONVERT(datetime, '08/16/2018 00:00:00', 121) and ot.record_time <= CONVERT(datetime, '08/16/2018 23:59:59', 121)

        order by el.Last_Name asc, ot.record_time asc
```

Output:

```
id      EID Name                        Time                Status
194664  125 MOQUETE, ABRAHAM JOSEPH Thu 08-16-2018 07:55:57 Time In
194703  125 MOQUETE, ABRAHAM JOSEPH Thu 08-16-2018 12:11:36 Time Out
194705  125 MOQUETE, ABRAHAM JOSEPH Thu 08-16-2018 12:28:12 Time In
194757  125 MOQUETE, ABRAHAM JOSEPH Thu 08-16-2018 20:45:08 Time Out
```

Currently I am able get the total work hours, and I want to get the Late and Overtime.

```
select
    employee_id as EID, 
    FORMAT(date, 'MM-dd-yyyy') as [Date], 
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date) as [Day],
    right(concat('00', diff / 4100), 2) + ':' + right(concat('00', diff % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('00', diff % 60), 2) as TWH
    from (select
            employee_id, 
            [date] = cast(actual_time as date), 
            diff = datediff(ss, min(iif(type = 0, actual_time, null)), max(iif(type = 1, actual_time, null)))
        from
            officer_timelogs
            where employee_id = (CASE WHEN @employee_id = 0 THEN employee_id else @employee_id END)
        group by employee_id, cast(actual_time as date)
        ) t
    where t.date >= @dateFrom and t.date <= @dateTo
    order by date asc
```

Expected Output:

```
EID Date        Day         TWH        Late    OT
125 08-16-2018  Thursday    11:49:11
```

Comment: Please post your table schema, sample data and expected result

Comment: @Squirrel i add my expected result.

Comment: how about your table schema and sample data ?

Comment: @Squirrel i include the screen capture of the results of each query.

Comment: your query involved several table like `tbl_payroll_schedule, employee_default_schedule, officer_timelogs, tbl_Employee_MasterList `. We need to know the schema of these tables, sample data. What you have shown is the result of the query. Also we prefer text rather than screen. Screen we can't copy and paste the data for testing. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You want late and overtime.  Woudn't you also need 'early in' and 'early out'?  Or are those just not permitted in the business rules?

Comment: @Greenspark we also need early in and early out if it is possible.

Comment: @AbrahamJosephMoquete I would suggest using Temp tables for an easier approach, so what you need to do is to insert the first query into a temp table (just add INTO #yourTempTableName before FROM) then you do the rest from the temp table itself. This would make things easier to maintain.

Comment: @AbrahamJosephMoquete I would suggest using Temp tables for an easier approach, so what you need to do is to insert the first query into a temp table (just add INTO #yourTempTableName before FROM) then you do the rest from the temp table itself. This would make things easier to maintain.